# How to preserve n lines of console for the same output?

Tags: c++, c, console, printf, cout

I'm using console intensively to report the status of my program.

There are different modules that print different messages of different importance.

What I want is to preserve the first two lines of the console to print some important information while allowing the other information to be printed in the rest of the console. Even if the other information exceeded one page of console and had to scroll down, I want the first two lines to stay there.

Is there some way to do this?

Currently, I'm printing using `printf` with colors.

I'm working on Linux and I'm using guake terminal (zsh). I'm using both C and C++ in my code so both are fine for me.

Comment: Not portably. For non-portably (Linux), look up ncurses or for Windows, look up the console functions on MSDN.

Comment: No, there is no way. First of all because C and C++ are different, and regarding this they are even more different, because C++ has different IO libraries. And more important than that is 1. You must provide some code and what you tried with it, 2. It's probably console specific and thus, operating system related. Also, note that the console has nothing to do with the programming language. You can probably check what type of terminal you're using and how you can manipulate it, probably through escape sequences.

Comment: The windows console has a buffer you can scroll which has far more (and configurable) lines than the old-time 25 lines.

Comment: As per your update specifying linux, I second immibis' suggestion. Definitely check out [ncurses](http://www.cs.ukzn.ac.za/~hughm/os/notes/ncurses.html#output). Create a dedicated print function that will move the cursor around to guarantee your two lines stay up top.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments and hints. I'll try ncurses.

Comment: IMHO, a better solution is to write to a log file.  Each entry should be prefixed with the date and time.  You can added other stuff for indicating importance.